# undeclared error with thread in OS X?

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLONE_FS'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLONE_FILES'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLONE_SIGHAND'
 error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLONE_VM'

i use ubuntu code some about processes and thread can run in ubuntu but in my mac give me this error.how can i fix it?  if i change this Macro to decimal this error disapper too.

```
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
sem_init(&product,0,0);
sem_init(&warehouse,0,8);
int clone_flag,arg,retval;
clone_flag = CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES;
int i;
char *stack;
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    arg = i;
    stack = (char *)malloc(4096);
    retval = clone((void *)producer,&(stack[4095]),clone_flag,(void *)&arg);
    stack = (char *)malloc(4096);
    retval = clone((void *)consumer,&(stack[4095]),clone_flag,(void *)&arg);
}
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you included `sched.h` ?

Comment: I thought `clone` was a Linux-specific thing. Are you sure that it even exists on OS X?

Comment: if i change those Macro to number it can run in my mac.

Comment: this code is no problem.i think my computer must missing some head file.but i don't know which i missing.

Comment: I just told you which one. On Linux at least it is.